# How do I properly display GregorianCalendar instances in Java?

Tags: java, formatting, gregorian-calendar

I have a couple of GregorianCalendar variables named 'budGitt' and 'budFrist', but when I add them to my toString method as such

```
public String toString() {
    return budGitt + "\t" + budFrist + "\t" +.......
}
```

the output looks like this for each instance

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1454203447510,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Oslo",offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=141,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Oslo,offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2016,MONTH=0,WEEK_OF_YEAR=4,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=31,DAY_OF_YEAR=31,DAY_OF_WEEK=1,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=5,AM_PM=0,HOUR=2,HOUR_OF_DAY=2,MINUTE=24,SECOND=7,MILLISECOND=510,ZONE_OFFSET=3600000,DST_OFFSET=0] java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1454246647509,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Oslo",offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=141,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Oslo,offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2016,MONTH=0,WEEK_OF_YEAR=4,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=31,DAY_OF_YEAR=31,DAY_OF_WEEK=1,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=5,AM_PM=1,HOUR=2,HOUR_OF_DAY=14,MINUTE=24,SECOND=7,MILLISECOND=509,ZONE_OFFSET=3600000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

How do I format this to make it readable?

Comment: The `GregorianCalendar` class is long outdated, so I recommend you don’t use it. Instead, find the class in [the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) that suits your need and use it instead for `budGitt` and `budFrist`. Its `toString` method will make sure you get a readable output from the code you have. My first thought is that the `Instant` class could be right, but it depends on your more exact requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the exact output you're looking for, but you should make use of `SimpleDateFormat` in order to make it more friendly. Here's an example.

```
public String getFriendlyCalendar(GregorianCalendar calendar){
    SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    dateTimeFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
    return dateTimeFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much.

Comment: I will as soon as I earn enough points.. Just joined. Much appreciated, mate!

Comment: `HH:MM:SS`? Please watch the case of you format pattern letters; capital M and capital S won’t give you the expected output.